# Поиск точного совпадения строки с экранированными символами в MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, escape

Мне нужно проверить заголовок статьи на уникальность. Решил сделать так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE `title` = 'Заголовок статьи'
```

Все работает, но если в строке есть экранированные символы, например:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE `title` = 'Заголовок \"статьи\" с кавычками'
```

то результат в `count` получается 0. Я понимаю, что чего-то не понимаю. Как правильно найти уникальный заголовок?

Comment: Скажем так `select 1 from DUAL where 'Заголовок \"статьи\" с кавычками' = 'Заголовок "статьи" с кавычками'` отлично возвращает 1. Значит либо у вас в базе строка лежит как то по другому, либо то через что вы выполняете запрос как то так интерполирует обратные косые

Comment: В том то и дело, что я, используя phpmyadmin, копирую строку из ячейки с заголовком, вставляю в запрос в том же phpmyadmin и получаю 0. Пробовал добавлять/убирать экранирование и менять одинарные кавычки на двойные. Получаю 0.

Comment: Тип данных varchar, сравнение uft8_general_ci, тип таблицы MyISAM.

Comment: тогда не пользуйтесь phpmyadmin, он черти что может творить. попробуйте непосредственно в утилите mysql в консоли. или какое нибудь нормальное средство работы с mysql возьмите, типа MySQL workbench (хотя к нему у меня то же масса вопросов по удобству) ...

Comment: Кстати .... может раз он показывает с обартными косыми - оно и лежит в базе с обратными косыми. тогда косые в запросе надо удваивать ... `'Заголовок \\"статьи\\" с кавычками'`

Comment: Да, действительно нужно вводить с двойными косыми... Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Используйте запрос вида

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  table
WHERE
  `title` = 'Заголовок \\"статьи\\" с кавычками'
```